# How to get and update nested document in mongo db using java

Tags: java, mongodb

I have a documents in mongo db as follows. I want to get and update the document having policyMap equals CostCalculation.In this CostCalculation has array format update in array elements such as 'policyName' have 'CostCalculationPolicyuserDefine' and set 'policyDes' = 'New Value' Please suggest the java code to solve this.

I searched mongo operartors but couldn't get it.

Sample  mongo db document structure.

```
{
"policyMap" : {
"CostCalculation" : [{
    "policyName" : "CostCalculationPolicyuserDefine",
    "policyDesc" : "Priority user Defined Policy",
    "userDefined" : 1
  },
  {
    "policyName" : "CostCalculationPolicyuserDefine1",
    "policyDesc" : "Priority user Defined Policy",
    "userDefined" : 1
  }]
},
"bsVer" : 2,
"bsFlag" : true,
"crBy" : "xxxxx",
"crDate" : NumberLong("1440138385345"),
"entNm" : "xxxx"
}
{
"policyMap" : {
"CostValue" : [{
    "policyName" : "CostValuePolicyuserDefine",
    "policyDesc" : "Priority user Defined Policy",
    "userDefined" : 1
  },
  {
    "policyName" : "CostCalculationPolicyuserDefine1",
    "policyDesc" : "Priority user Defined Policy",
    "userDefined" : 1
  }]
},
"bsVer" : 2,
"bsFlag" : true,
"crBy" : "xxxxx",
"crDate" : NumberLong("1440138385345"),
"entNm" : "xxxx"
}
```

My sample java code

```
DBCollection coll = db.getCollection("nestedtest");
BasicDBObject searchDocument = new BasicDBObject();
searchDocument.put( "policyMap ", new BasicDBObject("$exists", new  BasicDBObject("$eq", "CostCalculation")));
        coll.remove(searchDocument);
```

What would be the similar java code to get the correct result.

Thanks.

Comment: ["dot notation"](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/core/document/#dot-notation)

Comment: Could u Explain clearly.i didn't get how to perform this operation.

Comment: Have you read the material in the link? Or even this part from [Query Documents](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/query-documents/#equality-match-on-fields-within-an-embedded-document) in the core documentation?

Comment: sorry i couldn't get.could assist in this scenario

Comment: possible duplicate of [Retrieve only the queried element in an object array in MongoDB collection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985214/retrieve-only-the-queried-element-in-an-object-array-in-mongodb-collection)

Comment: i'm not agree this is not duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

This code works using Mongo 3 java drivers.  It removes the need for all the BasicDBObjects that are in your code:

```
    MongoClientURI uri = new MongoClientURI("mongodb://localhost:27017");
    MongoClient client = new MongoClient(uri);
    initialiseCollection(client);

    Bson filter = Filters.exists("policyMap.costCalculation");
    client.getDatabase("test").getCollection("test").deleteOne(filter);
```

Comment: we r using mongo-java-driver-2.1.13..jar.But one condition here 'costCalculation' will be come as dynamic which value come we don't know.Please suggest some other alternatives.@robjwilkins

Comment: can you upgrade the java driver?

Answer (score -1):

```
DBCollection coll = db.getCollection("minnalPolicyMetadata");
BasicDBObject searchDocument = new BasicDBObject();
searchDocument.put("policyMap.CostCalculation",new BasicDBObject("$exists",true));
DBCursor cursor = coll.find(searchDocument);                    
if(cursor.count() != 0){
while(cursor.hasNext())
System.out.println(cursor.next());

                    }
```

In this way i solved this problem.Use exists operator in mongo

Comment: This code is a mess.  Its poorly indented, has commented out lines, System.out.println statements in it, and doesnt appear to address the issue from the original question

Comment: In this using i'm using search operation.If you want to delete that record use col1.remove(condition).

Comment: How to do update in this document can any one help me please @robjwilkins